# Start up of the windows is been stopped by ubuntu

Tags: startup

I have uninstalled ubuntu but the bootstrap is still showing ubuntu before starting what to do?

Comment: You have to restore the Windows MBR.

Answer (score 0):

How did you uninstalled Ubuntu? Also, post here output of commands `lsblk` and `sudo blkid` using terminal.

Solution:
Go to BIOS(UEFI) and change boot option #1 (boot order) to **Windows Boot Manager**. (This will skip bootstrap (=grub) of Ubuntu and start Windows first.)

You can enter BIOS with pressing <kbd>Del</kbd>or <kbd>Esc</kbd>when computer is booting.